# Swift - help deciphering the call stack

Tags: swift, crash, stack

I'd like to know if there is anything in the crash stack that will help me get to the root of a "Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x600000986940> was mutated while being enumerated." error. From what I've learned so far, calling save context while enumerating can cause this problem. Although, I thought using .main.async would fix it. It does not. I think I need to figure out how to implement concurrency, but first I'd just like to know *where* the problem is happening.

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c4f6fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105c72ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c4c5cc __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
    3   CoreData                            0x00000001065c688f -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 2463
    4   ncdrainage                          0x0000000104f18e64 $s10ncdrainage15ApplicationDataC18deleteLocalRecords04listF7DeletedySDyS2SG_tF + 1572
    5   ncdrainage                          0x0000000104f106db $s10ncdrainage15ApplicationDataC15downloadUpdates13finishClosureyySo23UIBackgroundFetchResultVc_tFySo19CKServerChangeTokenCSg_Sbs5Error_pSgtcfU1_ySo14CKRecordZoneIDC_AJ10Foundation0C0VSgSbALtcfU2_ + 1115
    6   ncdrainage                          0x0000000104f2f09b $s10ncdrainage15ApplicationDataC15downloadUpdates13finishClosureyySo23UIBackgroundFetchResultVc_tFySo19CKServerChangeTokenCSg_Sbs5Error_pSgtcfU1_ySo14CKRecordZoneIDC_AJ10Foundation0C0VSgSbALtcfU2_TA + 59
    7   ncdrainage                          0x0000000104f109a4 $sSo14CKRecordZoneIDCSo19CKServerChangeTokenCSg10Foundation4DataVSgSbs5Error_pSgIeggggyg_AbESo6NSDataCSgSbSo7NSErrorCSgIeyByyyyy_TR + 372
    8   CloudKit                            0x00000001054f26a7 -[CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation _handleProgressCallback:] + 4864
    9   CloudKit                            0x00000001054ba54f -[CKOperation _handleProgressCallback:completion:] + 61
    10  CloudKit                            0x00000001054b6d3c __21-[CKOperation _start]_block_invoke.370 + 216
    11  CloudKit                            0x00000001055306c5 __68-[CKOperationCallbackManager _performCallbackForOperation:callback:]_block_invoke + 278
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010922d725 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010921fdb5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109227225 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 778
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109227ed0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 477
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109231ea3 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 733
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000109608611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001096083fd start_wqthread + 13
```

Comment: Properly symbolicate your crash report so you can see where in your own code it is crashing.

Comment: But it seems to be a problem in something called `deleteLocalRecords`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not as much as what there is in your crash stack, as what there isn't. Since there is no anything like NSManagedObjectContextPerform, it seems that you don't work with your context in the right thread. You should call code working with context from block submitted to NSManagedObjectContext::perform or NSManagedObjectContext::performAndWait.

So the code should be something like this:

```
func deleteObjects(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    context.perform {
        let objects = context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for object in objects {
            context.delete(object)
        }

        context.save()
    }
}
```

You can catch such issues in debug by enabling [core data concurrency debugging](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, if I create a managed object context using privateQueueConcurrencyType and then call it as you show in the sample above, I should be good? Or, at least, on the right track?

Comment: @squarehippo10 You should be good in a sense that context operations wouldn't cause strange crashes because of multithreading, but there still might be more work to synchronize data changes and UI and the like.